# Why records about python command-line launches do not saved in history

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, command-line, history

I quiet often launch python scripts from command-line, like `python somescript.py --with-arguments`

Now I'm wondering why that does not saved in output of `history` command?

And if there is a way to see history of it

Answer (score 1):

Bash usually saves all your commands in the history buffer except if you specifically mark them to be excluded.  There is an environment variable `HISTIGNORE` which might be configured to ignore `python` invocations altogether, although this is somewhat unlikely; or you may be marking them for exclusion by typing a space before the command.